# Python sum two list in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

can someone help me sum this two list. so first would be 10+1=11 then 20+2=22 then 30+3=33 and so on:

```
list1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
list2 = [[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]]
```

the output would be something like this:

```
list3[[11,22],[33,44],[55,66]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a possible solution:

```
list1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
list2 = [[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]]


def sum(list1, list2):
    new_list=[]
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        new_list.append([list1[i][j]+list2[i][j] for j in range(len(list1[i]))])
    return new_list  

print(sum(list1,list2))
```

[[11, 22], [33, 44], [55, 66]]
Thanks, and good python

Comment: Thank you!!! thats actually exactly what i needed!

Comment: Hi @AdamSmith if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.